# Android ListView "recycle" doesn't store rows which are not visible initially

Tags: android, android-listview, listadapter, layout-inflater

There are maybe thousands of posts around the web about ListView and ListAdapter recycle process but I couldn't solve my problem so far.

I have custom ListView rows and populate the items inside the rows (TextViews, ImageViews, etc.) with the data I get from remote server. The screen can show 5 rows maximum at a time and I have to scroll if I have more rows. The problem is; the adapter stores and recycles only the first 5 rows' information and even if I scroll to see the 6th, 7th, 8th, etc. rows I see the same 5 rows again and again at random positions.

Here is the code:

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<String> id, name, address;
    private Context context;

    public ListAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<String> id,
            ArrayList<String> name, ArrayList<String> address,) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.context = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return id.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return id.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int id) {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowsLayout;

        if (convertView == null) {
            rowsLayout = (View)LayoutInflater.from(context)
                           .inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            //Assign values to TextViews in here
        } else {
            rowsLayout = convertView;
        }
            return rowsLayout;
    }
}
```

I tried using the method in [this website](http://mobile.cs.fsu.edu/the-nuance-of-android-listview-recycling-for-n00bs/) but it didn't help.

If anybody can offer me a solution (with code please) or direct me to another post I will be grateful.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16515077/widget-in-listview-disappears-when-listview-scrolls-down/16515327#16515327

Answer (score 0):

Change your code from this:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowsLayout;

    if (convertView == null) {
        rowsLayout = (View)LayoutInflater.from(context)
                       .inflate(R.layout.servisler_list_item, null);
        //Assign values to TextViews in here
    } else {
        rowsLayout = convertView;
    }
        return servisRowsLayout;
}
```

to this:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowsLayout;

    if (convertView == null) {
        rowsLayout = (View)LayoutInflater.from(context)
                       .inflate(R.layout.servisler_list_item, null);
    } else {
        rowsLayout = convertView;
    }

        //Assign values to TextViews in here

        return servisRowsLayout;
}
```

You need to "Assign values to TextViews" on **every** `getView()` call, not just some of them.

Comment: I should have mentioned that in my original post; I cannot do this because I have too many items (including images) in the rows and it slows the scroll terribly. I am looking for a way to disable recycling and keeping the rows permanently actually, because I will never have more than 15-16 rows at a given time.

Comment: @EnginYapici: "I cannot do this because I have too many items (including images) in the rows and it slows the scroll terribly" -- then you are doing something wrong on the main application thread, such as loading images from disk/network. "I am looking for a way to disable recycling and keeping the rows permanently actually, because I will never have more than 15-16 rows at a given time" -- override `getViewTypeCount()` to return `getCount()` and return `getItemViewType()` to return `position`, so Android thinks each row is unique. Haven't tried this, but it should work.

Comment: @EnginYapici: And note that the hack that I described is still a much worse idea than just fixing your performance problem in the first place.